# Getting unsupported attribute error in terraform when using for_each expression

Tags: terraform

Using **for_each** expression in Terraform v0.12.6  to dynamically generate inline blocks of vnet subnets (Azure). I have list variable 'subnets' defined, with two subnets 'sub1' and 'sub2' as below

```
variable "subnets" {
  default = [
    {
      name   = "sub1"
      prefix = "1.1.1.1/32"
    },
    {
      name   = "sub2"
      prefix = "2.2.2.2/32"
    },
  ]
}
```

then iterate over list variable inside "azurerm_virtual_network" block to create dynamic blocks of subnets

```
dynamic "subnet" {
    for_each = [for s in var.subnets  : { 
        name   = s.name
        prefix = s.prefix
    }]

    content {
      name           = subnet.name
      address_prefix = subnet.prefix
    }   
  }
}
```

Getting i.e. first one is  **Error: Unsupported attribute**

*on main.tf line 42, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet":
  42:       name           = subnet.name*

This object does not have an attribute named "name".

Comment: `for s in var.subnets` should work for iteration without that `for_each`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The iterator object created for a `dynamic` block has two attributes:

- `key`: the map key or list index of the current element
- `value`: the value of the current element

In this case, the collection being used for repetition is a list of objects, so `subnet.key` will be integer indices 0, 1, ... and `subnet.value` will be the object associated with that index.

To get the result you were looking for, you'll need to access the object attributes on `subnet.value` instead:

```
dynamic "subnet" {
    for_each = [for s in var.subnets  : { 
        name   = s.name
        prefix = s.prefix
    }]

    content {
      name           = subnet.value.name
      address_prefix = subnet.value.prefix
    }   
  }
}
```

It seems like `var.subnets` is already compatible with the object structure the `content` block expects, so it may be possible to simplify this further by accessing it directly:

```
dynamic "subnet" {
    for_each = var.subnets

    content {
      name           = subnet.value.name
      address_prefix = subnet.value.prefix
    }   
  }
}
```

As long as `var.subnets` is a list of objects already, this should produce an identical result.